# "Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED" While running query from JMeter

Tags: jmeter

The following query I am trying to execute it from JMeter,

```
DECLARE 
j number(4)
BEGIN 
FOR j in 11 .. 12 LOOP
      INSERT INTO FWA_STAGE_TU 
      (ID,EXT_ID,BATCH_NO,OPERATION,BLOCK_ROLL_UP_LAST_RECORD,LAST_UPDATED_DATE,ERROR_FLAG,TRIAL_NO,TRIAL_ALIAS_CODE,
      COUNTRY_CODE,DISPLAY_UNIT_NO,GROUP_NO,TRIAL_UNIT_REFERENCE,PRIMARY_INVESTIGATOR,PRIMARY_CENTRE,OCATION_NO,
      PURPOSE_CODE,MANAGING_MED_UNIT_CODE,UPDATING_MED_UNIT_CODE,FINANCE_MED_UNIT_CODE,PATIENTS_ALL_SET_UP_FLAG,
      PATIENT_MONITORING_FLAG,COMMENTS,CONFIRMED_FLAG,CONFIRMED_BY,CONFIRMED_DATE,ROLLUP_ROLLDOWN_PLANNED_FIGS,
      DOC_COLLECTION_INDICATOR,VALIDATED_PAT_CAP,MAXIMUM_PAT_CAP,PREFERRED_LANGUAGE_CODE,NEW_DISPLAY_UNIT_NO,
      TOTAL_OPEN_DCF_ISSUES_NO,ORDER_INTERVAL,ORDER_INTERVAL_UNITS,DATA_SOURCE_CODE,RANK_SEQ)                  
      VALUES 
      (j, 1, 10, 'I', NULL, SYSDATE, 'N', 102922, 'TESTTRIAL4', 'BEL', 
      j, NULL, 'BELTU'||j, 130262, 124236, NULL, 'PATTR', 'FP', 'FP', 'FP', 'N', 'Y', 'TESTTU'||j, 
      'Y', 999999, SYSDATE, NULL, 'P', 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); 
  END LOOP
END
```

When I wrap them the entire query inside `"DECLARE .....END"` and execute I am getting the following errors,

With

1. `transaction isolation` type `'TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE'` and Query Type `callable` I am getting `Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED`
2. `transaction isolation` type `'TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE'` and Query Type `update` I am getting `Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED`

When I wrap them `""` and `+` at the end of every line something like

```
"DECLARE" +.......
"j number(4)" + ......"END LOOP" +....
"END"
```

1. `transaction isolation` type `'TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE'` and Query Type `callable` I am getting `Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED`
2. `transaction isolation` type `'TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE'` and Query Type `update` I am getting `Invalid SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED`

When I wrap them inside `{call .... }`  something like
`{call DECLARE ......END}` I am getting

```
ORA-06550: line 3, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:

   := ; not null default character
The symbol ";" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 17, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:

   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.
```

How to resolve this issue ? It worked fine from Oracle SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

Transaction isolation level has nothing to do with your problem, see [Using JDBC Sampler in JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733769-Using-JDBC-Sampler-in-JMeter?mobile_site=true) article for comprehensive information on what each setting mean.

Your problem is that you're trying to run PL/SQL script and you're supposed to provide an SQL statement.

The options are in:

1. Create a [stored procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm) in your Oracle DB and invoke the stored procedure using JMeter's "Callable Statement"
2. Wrap your PL/SQL script into [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm)
3. Use JMeter's [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) instead of Oracle's loop in order to run your INSERT query as many times as you need